# TypeDecorator subclass trying to compare against NO_VALUE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a subclass `myTypeSA` of `sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator` that defines `process_bind_param` and `process_result_value` as follows to allow persistance of `myType` instances to the database:

```
    class myTypeSA(types.TypeDecorator):
        """ Decorate String type to translate myType instance into String in the database"""
        impl = types.String(15)

        def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
            if value is None:
                return None
            assert type(value) == myType
            return value.as_str()

        def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
            if value is None:
                return None
            return myType.from_str(value)
```

At some point in a commit, sqlalchemy seems to try to see if an object has changed, and calls `TypeDecorator.compare_values` which defaults to sa.String  `compare_values` , ie `TypeEngine.compare_values`.  This is really just `x == y` , which asserts in my case because x is an instance of `myType` and y is a sqlalchemy string : `NO_VALUE` .

I'm tempted to override directly `TypeDecorator.compare_values` to fix this issue but I wonder if I missed something and should override `coerce_compared_value` or `process_literal_param` ; the comments detailing when those methods are used are not very clear to me. How should that comparison against `NO_VALUE` have been handled?

Thanks